How to share iPhone screen to Mac?
Back in the day I was using this trick: https://medium.com/mac-os-x/how-to-mirror-your-smart-phone-screen-in-mac-os-x-2daf018aae4d


Launch Quick Time Player in your Mac.
Select New Movie Recording under File Menu (⌘+⌥ + N)
In the popup window select the down arrow
near record button.
Choose the iPhone as your camera and microphone
if needed.
That’s it. Now you are mirroring the iPhone screen on
your Mac.


BUT:

I'm pretty sure I've enabled all the permissions when connecting my iPhone via USB-C cable that is capable of transmitting data, not a dumb cable.

I just want to take a screenshot from an app that prevents me from taking screenshots, I thought that connecting to Mac is the simplest, I may just use another camera and then enhance in Photoshop.

If system requirements are met then Apple supported way would be iPhone mirroring: Use your iPhone from your Mac

Would you be happy with another way to take a screenshot directly on your phone ? How are you attempting the screenshot whilst in the app ?

I am using iOS 15.8.3 on my phone and OS Catalina on my Mac. On your phone, go to Assistive touch in settings, toggle it on and a virtual 'home' button appears. I then assign 'screenshot' to the 'double-tap' custom action. Double-tapping the virtual home button then takes a screenshot. It may work for your troublesome app. Otherwise I successfully use the 'LetsView' app to mirror my iphone screen to my imac. Download 'LetsView' on both your Mac and your phone and follow the somewhat confusing instructions. You will need to allow screen sharing in 'Sharing' in preferences on your Mac.
